# Is it possible to remediate AWS config rules from Centralized account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations, aws-config

If I do AWS config Multi account configuration  and aggregate all the data to the centralized account.

Could I configure rules and create remediate actions from the centralized  account ?

Does cross account  remediation  work for AWS config?

Comment: see also https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/add-config-remediation-actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does cross account remediation work for AWS config?

Its possible, but this is something that needs to be setup and is not provided out-of-the box. Such setup could involve:

- a remediation lambda function in the master account.
- IAM roles in member accounts that the lambda can assume.
- SSM document created in the master account and shared with the member accounts.

An example of such architecture with CloudFormation templates and explanation is given in [Manage custom AWS Config rules with remediation using conformance packs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/manage-custom-aws-config-rules-with-remediations-using-conformance-packs/)